# Java : What happens when Connection object is nullified without calling Connection.close()

Tags: java, null, connection, store

What happens with the connection established with database if a instance of `java.sql.Connection` as `con` is nullified.

```
con = null;
```

Is the connection closed or remains open till the application is running.
**2nd Question :**
Similarly if have an instance of `javax.mail.Store` as `store` and nullify it ,

```
store = null;
```

will the smtp connection be closed or remains unclosed.
Thanks.

Comment: Which Connection class ? and post one question at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your `Connection` to null, this connection will remain "open" and the code associated with close will not be run. Hence in order to close it you must call the `close()` method. 
If the connection is not closed, other resources that might be held by the connection won't be released either

Comment: "code associated with close will not be run": you don't know that. It might. It might have a finalize() method.

Answer (score 2):

If you make your `connection` instance null without calling `close()` then,

`connection`  would be ready to be garbage collected

and it will not invoke the code that is required to do with `close()` method's implementation

Comment: "will not invoke the code": you don't know that. It might. It might have a finalize() method.

Answer (score 1):

There's finalize method and it's very likely that concrete implementation of the Connection or Store will override this method and call close() there. For example here's snippet from PostgreSQL JDBC Driver:

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
{
    if (openStackTrace != null)
        logger.log(GT.tr("Finalizing a Connection that was never closed:"), openStackTrace);

    close();
}
```

This method will be called when garbage collector decides that it's time to collect given object.

But it's recommended to always close connections and similar resources manually, because garbage collector is unpredictable. You can hit connection limit faster than garbage collector will start and free resources, for example.